# StateException: Annotation-specified bean name

Tags: java, spring

I get the following exception :

> StateException: Annotation-specified bean name
>   'scenarioServiceImpl' for bean class
>   [com.company.project.services.autoExec.ScenarioService] conflicts with existing, non->compatible bean
>   definition of same name and >class[com.company.project.services.autoExec.ScenarioServiceImpl]     >at
>   org.springframework.ontext.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPath>BeanDefinitionScanner.java:274)

here are the signatures of both the class and interface :

```
public interface ScenarioService 



@Component("scenarioServiceImpl")
public class ScenarioServiceImpl implements ScenarioService
```

I really don't understand why spring attributes the name I specified in the implementation, to the interface and end up with a conflict .

PS : I'm not using xml based configuration, so rest assured there's no conflict.

Comment: The name you provided in the `@Component` is the name that Spring would be giving it had you not provided a name.  I imagine that is where the conflict is coming from.  Try changing the name just a bit, or removing the name altogether.